# i need to combine unique keys and their values grouping as list in python

Tags: python-2.7

mylist=[{'apple':1,'mango':2},{'apple':3,'orange':10,'mango':15}]

#### i need like this

Heading

mylist=[{'apple':[1,3],'mango':[2,15],'orange':[0,10]}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here List of dictionary items:

```
example = [{'apple':1,'mango':2},{'apple':3,'orange':10,'mango':15}]
name=[]
for key_name in example:
    for i in key_name:
        if i not in name:
            name.append(i)

for ks in example:
    storeKey=[{listKey:0} for listKey in list(set(name)-set(ks.keys()))]
    for s in storeKey:
        for k,v in s.items():
            ks.update({k:v});

new = {}
for d in example:
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        new.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print new
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this??

```
example = [{'apple':1,'mango':2},{'apple':3,'orange':10,'mango':15}]

new = {}
for d in example:
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        new.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print new
```

Comment: go for it then man... ive given you the basic idea maybe try some things out. accept answer?

Answer (score -1):

`example = [{'apple':1,'mango':2},{'apple':3,'orange':10,'mango':15}]
new ={}

[[ks.update({k:v}) for s in [{listKey:0} for listKey in list(set(list(set(i for key_name in example for i in key_name)))-set(ks.keys()))] for k,v in s.items()] for ks in example]
[new.setdefault(k, []).append(v) for d in example for k,v in d.iteritems()]
print new`